# how to deploy a smartcontract on the mainnet

Tags: go-ethereum, mainnet

I used truffle to create a smartcontract, and then deployed it on Rinkeby (using a local geth node) with this command. It works well.
`truffle migrate --network rinkeby`

The smartcontract is an updated version of this sample:
https://medium.com/cryptronics/ethereum-development-guide-part-1-ad0c77c3683f

Now I'd like to deploy the smartcontract on the mainnet:

```
$ geth --syncmode light --rpc --datadir=$HOME/mainnet --nousb --allow-insecure-unlock
$ geth --nousb account new --datadir="$HOME/mainnet/" --password ./account-password.txt
$ truffle migrate --network mainnet

"Migrations" exceeded the block limit (with a gas value you set).
   * Block limit:  5000 (0x1388) * Gas sent:     4000000 (0x3d0900)  * Try: + Sending less gas.
```

I changed truffle-config.js to use a bas of 10000. By the way, how much ETH does it costs currently to deploy a simple contract, more or less? what gas should I define?

```
$ truffle migrate --network mainnet
"Migrations" -- Returned error: getDeleteStateObject (1422d7ccc0d1b857e00bef1c265b8907071434d9) error: no suitable peers available.
```

It seems that's not trivial to set-up a geth node. So I tried using a free development node from [quiknode.io](https://www.quiknode.io/). But they do not support deploying a contract using truffle from the command line (only from its front end client Drizzle).

How can I deploy the smartcontract to mainnet?
I prefer command line tools, rather than graphical interfaces. However, both solutions are appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There you go (tested with web3.js v1.2.1):

```
const fs   = require("fs");
const Web3 = require("web3");

const NODE_ADDRESS  = "https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/YourProjectID";
const PRIVATE_KEY   = "0xYourPrivateKey";
const CONTRACT_NAME = "YourContractName";
const CONTRACT_ARGS = ["arg1", "arg2", "arg3"];
const ARTIFACTS_DIR = "RelativePathToYourAbiAndBinFolder";

async function scan(message) {
    process.stdout.write(message);
    return await new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        process.stdin.resume();
        process.stdin.once("data", function(data) {
            process.stdin.pause();
            resolve(data.toString().trim());
        });
    });
}

async function getGasPrice(web3) {
    while (true) {
        const nodeGasPrice = await web3.eth.getGasPrice();
        const userGasPrice = await scan(`Enter gas-price or leave empty to use ${nodeGasPrice}: `);
        if (/^\d+$/.test(userGasPrice))
            return userGasPrice;
        if (userGasPrice == "")
            return nodeGasPrice;
        console.log("Illegal gas-price");
    }
}

async function getTransactionReceipt(web3) {
    while (true) {
        const hash = await scan("Enter transaction-hash or leave empty to retry: ");
        if (/^0x([0-9A-Fa-f]{64})$/.test(hash)) {
            const receipt = await web3.eth.getTransactionReceipt(hash);
            if (receipt)
                return receipt;
            console.log("Invalid transaction-hash");
        }
        else if (hash) {
            console.log("Illegal transaction-hash");
        }
        else {
            return null;
        }
    }
}

async function send(web3, account, transaction) {
    while (true) {
        try {
            const options = {
                data    : transaction.encodeABI(),
                gas     : await transaction.estimateGas({from: account.address}),
                gasPrice: await getGasPrice(web3),
            };
            const signed  = await web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction(options, account.privateKey);
            const receipt = await web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(signed.rawTransaction);
            return receipt;
        }
        catch (error) {
            console.log(error.message);
            const receipt = await getTransactionReceipt(web3);
            if (receipt)
                return receipt;
        }
    }
}

async function run() {
    const web3        = new Web3(NODE_ADDRESS);
    const account     = web3.eth.accounts.privateKeyToAccount(PRIVATE_KEY);
    const path        = __dirname + "/" + ARTIFACTS_DIR + "/" + CONTRACT_NAME;
    const abi         = fs.readFileSync(path + ".abi", {encoding: "utf8"});
    const bin         = fs.readFileSync(path + ".bin", {encoding: "utf8"});
    const contract    = new web3.eth.Contract(JSON.parse(abi));
    const options     = {data: "0x" + bin, arguments: CONTRACT_ARGS};
    const transaction = contract.deploy(options);
    const receipt     = await send(web3, account, transaction);
    console.log("contract deployed at", receipt.contractAddress);
    if (web3.currentProvider.constructor.name == "WebsocketProvider")
        web3.currentProvider.connection.close();
}

run();
```

Comment: thanks. where does this code come from? you wrote it yourself? is it available in github or somewhere else?

Comment: @DavidPortabella: I wrote it.

Comment: i would prefer to use existing tools/scripts ;)

Comment: @DavidPortabella: That IS an existing tool. Tested and used for a very long time!